# Handle press and release of button

Tags: c#, button

I want a button to function like this:

```
if button is down(mouse button is hold down)
{
   bool trySmthing = true;
}

if button is up
{
   bool trySmthing = false;
}
```

I tried some stuff with `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events but they don't give the right result.

Comment: What are you using, WinForms/Web application?

Comment: You mean the MouseDown and MouseUp events of a Button control? Or do you mean a keyboard key by "button"?

Comment: button as in a button control. does mouseUP/MouseDown also work for touch screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the focus must be in your application; a tutorial on handling the mouse events via the .NET framework in C# can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The `MouseDown` event, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the `MouseUp` event, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), are of particular interest..

Comment: Do these also work for touch screens? I'm programming on my laptop now but later on, it will be used on a touch screen.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think so - due to backwards compatibility, I would expect that a touch screen, driver-wise, also generates mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [Micosoft Library for C# Mouse-events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
void MouseUpHandler(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
// This method is called whenever the PreviewMouseUp event fires.
}

void MouseDownHandler(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
// This method is called whenever the PreviewMouseDown event fires.
}
```